# Unhide disk partition that was hid on previously installed Windows system

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, multi-boot, data-recovery, partition-recovery

so I needed to hide a partition on my *external HDD*. In Windows 7 *Disk Manager* I simply removed the letter assigned to the partition and that was it (exactly like here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vs-913CnouM).

When I tried to unhide it a year later (by assigning a new letter to the partition), it says that the partition needs to be formatted = the partition has its letter but appears **unformatted** / RAW partion.

I guess the problem is that I´m now using *Windows 10* instead of the previous Windows 7, where the hiding was made. The Windows 7 partition on my internal drive is not deleted yet but I somehow cannot boot it again (Windows 10 is installed on another internal partition as I wanted to use 2 systems in my computer.)

Does anyone know how to get to my files on the previously hidden partition on my external HDD? or at least how to boot the old WIndows 7 partition when it doesn´t show up in the boot options menu. Should I use third party data recovery software like Data Rescue or Recuva to access the partition or, at worst, recover all my files sector ba sector?

Thank you for any help

**UPDATE:**

The device is healthy according to Disc Manager. I haven´t touched the external HDD in 8 months since I hid the partition. So the act of unhiding is made directly after that. I think I might have assigned a bad *SYSTEM ID* to a partition, when trying to unhide, and so it is not recognised as readable now. I chose **07** (in diskpart), which is NTFS. However, maybe the original was another one, perhaps the Apple´s **HFS+**.

**Is there any way I can change the PARTITION SYSTEM ID to HFS+ in a Windows 10 computer?** Did I damaged the files by changing the system ID? Is it safe to use recovery tools like Data Rescue when the system ID is messed up?

thanks a lot, it´s 700gb of data.

**UPDATE 2** (following the advice from user TOOGAM):

It is MBR and there are currently 3 partitions. It is a 1.5TB 3,5" external HDD. The other two working partitions are both 0x7 (Partition type ID). The first one is unknown, but I remember it was either HFS+ or NTFS.

The **FIRST PARTITION** shows UNFORMATTED, 652.33 GB, first physical sector (fps) 63, last physical sector (lps) 1368035646. 
The **SECOND PARTITION** is 0x7, 326.09 GB, fps 1368035676, lps 2061895299. 
The **THIRD PARTITION** is 0x7, 418.85 GB, fps 205189532, lps 2930277167.

What should I do next? thanks

Comment: You not being able to do this has nothing to do with Windows 10, it has everything to do with the health of the device, if its asking you format the drive its because the file system is gone.

Comment: The device is healthy according to Disc Manager. I haven´t touched the external HDD in 8 months since I hid the partition. So the act of unhiding is made directly after that. I thinks I might have assigned a bad SYSTEM ID to a partition and so it is not recognised as readable. I chose 07, which is NTFS. Maybe it was another one, perhaps the Apple´s HFS+. Is there any way I can change the PARTITION SYSTEM ID to HFS+ in a Windows 10 computer? thanks a lot, it´s 700gb of data.

Comment: This sounds like a good chance of being able to recover everything.  Find out if you are using MBR or GPT.  Also, find what partition identifier (often called the "Partition Type" if you are using MBR) each of your partitions is, and the start and ending sector of each partition.  When working with MBRs, some of the nicest ways to report all of that are with OpenBSD's fdisk, or Ranish Partition Manager (which is a DOS program).  However, many "fdisk" programs can show this type of data.

Comment: Thank you, TOOGAM. I really hope this will work. So, it is MBR and there are currently 3 partitions. It is a 1.5TB 3,5" external HDD. The other two working partitions are both 0x7 (Partition type ID). The first one is unknown, but I remember it was either HFS+ or NTFS. So the FIRST PARTITION shows UNFORMATTED, 652.33 GB, first physical sector (fps) 63, last physical sector (lps) 1368035646. The SECOND PARTITION is 0x7, 326.09 GB, fps 1368035676, lps 2061895299. The THIRD PARTITION is 0x7, 418.85 GB, fps 205189532, lps 2930277167. What should I do next? thanks

Comment: Hi @TOOGAM , do you think I have a chance to save the partition? Thanks very much in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when moving a drive to a newer version of Windows. Using HxD on the partition table worked for me. Although this article is related to a dynamic disk, it is still the same fix, "07" should be in the field for NTFS.

Instructions - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QQgRkEuFQac

The Microsoft supported utility is dskprobe.exe. Instructions:

> **This ONLY works if you have NOT used ANY of the new features of dynamic disks such as extending a partition or software RAID.
>
> 1) Install dskprobe.exe on the system. (This is one of the utilities in the Windows 2000 support tools on the install CD, and can
>   be installed by simply copying the .exe file to the hard drive.)
>
> 2) Run dskprobe.exe on the system.
>
> 3) Select the Drives menu and "Physical Drive. . ."
>
> 4) Double click on the drive that you want to convert back to a basic disk. Click the "Set Active" button next to that drive.
>
> 5) From the Sectors menu, select "Read"
>
> 6) Accept the defaults (begin sector 0, read 1 sector) and click "Read"
>
> 7) In the editor, go to the "01C0" line and the third bit should be a "42". Change that to a "07". **Note, a few machines have had this
>   on the "01D0" line instead. I don't know what that means, so I
>   wouldn't try it unless it is on a pure test box. *****
>
> 8) From the Sectors menu, select "Write". Confirm all dialog boxes. **Note: This is the step that will hose your box if you have
>   not followed the above instructions correctly.**
>
> 9) Exit dskprobe.exe. Reboot
>
> 10) Run chkdsk on the affected logical drive(s). If any errors are found, do a chkdsk /f to fix them. Done.

Source: http://www.nthelp.com/NT6/dynamic.htm

Comment: writing things in dummy guide format is a really inefficient way of giving instructions

Comment: @barlop, not for us dummies.  :-)

Comment: @RandySchuman - Its fine now, but please quote, any text that are not your own original words.

Comment: @RandySchuman - use quote blocks exactly how you would use quotation marks in professional writing.

Comment: @RandySchuman - You have never quoted something?  So if I go to that link, I won't find, a single sentence from your answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to Windows version. Something has damaged that partition's filesystem. Some (or all) data may be lost.

If you've had valuable files on that drive, you should look for professional data recovery service. If it's not that valuable, you can try to recover files off damaged partition yourself - but you're risking damaging it further if you don't do it carefully.

I can recommend [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) for file recovery. It will scan file byte by byte looking for recognizable files. This approach is filesystem-independent, so it should be sufficient to salvage whatever is left on that partition. It can possibly recover some deleted files too.

You should not perform recovery on actual partition. Prepare some spare disk space on another drive and create an uncompressed 1:1 partition image. PhotoRec will be able to work on that partition image file instead of actual disk.

It may be a good idea to check disk's SMART readings, too. Data corruption may indicate that the drive is in a bad shape and should be replaced.

Answer (score -3):

Boot into pe off a stick. run diskpart -attributes -clear hidden on the hidden volume. You can see the volume is hidden in diskpart.

Comment: Read the question, not just the title.